# Python- Changing element within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested, element

I'm trying to change an element within a list of lists. Here is my code and I'm using python version 3:

```
myboard = []

colList = []
#makes a 2D list/array of the rows and colums
for i in range(columns):
    colList.append(0)

for x in range(rows):
    myboard.append(colList)


myboard[0][1] = 999

print(myboard[0][1])
```

When I do this, it changes all the 1'th elements in each list to 999. Help please!

Comment: replace `myboard.append(colList)` with `myboard.append(colList.copy())`

Answer (score 2):

your error is due the fact that colList is the pointer to a list and not a list itself. 
If you want to have "independent" list in each element of `myboard` you have to replace
`myboard.append(colList)` with `myboard.append(colList.copy())`

In this way each element of myboard will be a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

## Short Solution:

---

As Donbeo pointed out you must replace `myboard.append(colList)` with `myboard.append(colList.copy)`

## Why:

---

Because in python when you make a reference (with in bar) to any mutable object (lets call it foo) its a exact replica, forever. So for instance `foo = [1,2,3]` and `bar = [foo, foo, foo]` makes `bar = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`. Now lets say you change foo to `[3,2,1]` then bar updates and becomes `[[3,2,1],[3,2,1],[3,2,1]]`. So, what is wrong with `bar[0][1] = 999`. Well, `bar[0] == foo` therefore `bar[0][1] == foo[1]`.
Now in python there's a easy fix! Lists have a copy method which creates a replica that does not change when foo does. For example `foo = [1,2,3]` and `bar = [foo.copy, foo.copy]`; now try `bar[0][1] = 999`. <s>ITS ALIVE</s>It works correctly. Now `bar[1][1] != bar[0][1]`.

## Demo

---

[Demo](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=foo+%3D+%5B1,2,3%5D%0Abar+%3D+%5Bfoo,+foo,+foo%5D+%23+wrong%0Aquux+%3D+%5Bfoo.copy(),+foo.copy(),+foo.copy()%5D+%23+right%0Aprint(bar)%0Aprint(quux)%0Abar%5B0%5D%5B1%5D+%3D+999%0Aquux%5B0%5D%5B1%5D+%3D+999%0Aprint(bar)%0Aprint(quux)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=true&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0)